# Page reloading even after preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Here Below Is My jS code. The problem is that it works fine when we load .recent-orders div for  changing pages but when i click on the details text it reloads the page and dont show preloader instead it loads and move towards next page. I want it not to reload and move towards next page showing preloader for 1 sec.

[image]

Desire page to come but shouldnot reload page
[image]

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let sideMenu = document.querySelector("aside");
  let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn");
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-btn");
  let themeToggler = document.querySelector(".theme-toggler");
  let detailCustomerEach = document.querySelectorAll(".detail_c_each");
  let sidebar_a = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar_a");
  let alerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");

  $(menuBtn).click(function () {
    sideMenu.style.display = "block";
    $(sideMenu).removeClass("animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft");
    $(sideMenu).addClass("animate__animated animate__slideInLeft");
  });

  $(sidebar_a).click(function (e) {
    // load another page without reloading

    if ($(sidebar_a).hasClass("active")) {
      $(sidebar_a).removeClass("active");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    setTimeout(() => {
      let url = $(this).attr("href");
      // show page content and change the url
      $(".recent-orders").load(url + " .recent-orders", function () {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
      });
    }, 1000);
    $(".recent-orders").load("./inc/preloader.html");
  });

  $(detailCustomerEach).click(function (e) {
    // load section detail customer without reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    let url1 = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(".recent-orders").load(url1 + " .recent-orders", function () {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, url1);
      });
    }, 5000);
  });

  // hide alert after 2 seconds
  $(alerts).each(function () {
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
      }.bind(this),
      2000
    );
  });

  $(closeBtn).click(function () {
    // sideMenu.style.display = "none";
    $(sideMenu).removeClass("animate__animated animate__slideInLeft");
    $(sideMenu).addClass("animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft");
  });

  $(".add-product").click(function () {
    window.open("./index", "_self");
  });

  // change theme
  $(themeToggler).click(function () {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme-variables");
    themeToggler.querySelector("span:nth-child(1)").classList.toggle("active");
    themeToggler.querySelector("span:nth-child(2)").classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

HTML Main

```
<div class="recent-orders">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <table id="recent-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Id</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->

                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=30"> Details </a> </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>UZAIR</td>
                <td>Lahore</td>
                <td class="success">03233337187</td>

                <!-- Classes available for status text color warning,success,danger,primary -->
                <td class="primary"> <a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=32"> Details </a> </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="show-all">Show All</a>
</div>
```

Html to move

```
<?php


$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "stinkspolitics_pl";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $pass, $dbname);



if (isset($_GET['detail_customer'])) {
    $quest_id = $_GET['detail_customer'];

    $get_quest = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quest_id = '$quest_id'";
    $getting_quest = mysqli_query($conn, $get_quest);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getting_quest)) {
        $quest_title = $row['quest_title'];
        $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    }
}



?>


<div class="recent-orders cust_det ">
    <h2> Customer Detail</h2>
    <div class="customer_detail">
        <form id="form" method="POST" action="" class="c_form animate__animated animate__fadeIn">

            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                            <strong>Success!</strong> Your question has been submitted.
                        </div>";
            }
            if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                            <strong>Sorry!</strong> Your question has not been submitted.
                        </div>";
            }
            ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $category_id  ?>" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="quest_t" value="<?php echo $quest_title  ?>" id="quest_t">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>

                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="submit-btn" class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $quest_t = $_POST['quest_t'];

    $update = "UPDATE questions SET quest_title = '$quest_t' WHERE quest_id = '$quest_id'";
    $run_update = mysqli_query($conn, $update);

    if ($run_update) {
        echo "<script>window.open('index?detail_customer=$quest_id&success', '_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you define URL to `href` it will being always redirect to that page

```
<a class="detail_c_each" href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a>
```

alternate solution

HTML code

```
<a class="detail_c_each" herf="javascript:void(0)" data-href="./index?detail_customer=31"> Details </a>
```

JS code

```
$(detailCustomerEach).click(function (e) {
    // load section detail customer without reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    let url1 = $(this).attr("data-href");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(".recent-orders").load(url1 + " .recent-orders", function () {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, url1);
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
```

I hope this solution will work for you

Comment: it works. but new problem is that if i go back and again click on detail.nothing happens

Comment: @MuhammadUzair Remove e.preventDefault(); from the detailCustimerEach click. It should work then.

Comment: When i click on it shows 404 not found something jquery cdn.

Comment: I am using jquery cdn in my main file

Comment: jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2          GET http://localhost/admin_panel/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @MuhammadUzair I am not sure if this related with given snippet. If you provide something more details then I can help you more

Comment: it is now working but the problem is if i put $(".recent-orders").load("./inc/preloader.html"); in detailCustomerEach click. it doesnot show. if i remove $(".recent-orders").load("./inc/preloader.html"); then it works

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. it shows this error but it has reloaded 1 minute ago but not working now

Comment: the problem is that it is sometime working but most of the time it is not working

Comment: I have noticed one thing that if it opens if we go back and try open  it again, it is not opening. but if we refresh page main page than it opens. Whats the reason of this?

Comment: Might be because of you have used window.history.pushState but not sure

Comment: should i remove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244265/discussion-between-kishan-vaishnani-and-muhammad-uzair).